# Zend Framework & ZfcTwig Module

Tags: php, zend-framework, twig

I'm integrating a template into a zend project, come from a Kohana background so a bit stuck on something. The project is split into two modules, admin and application.

The login page in the admin module uses the layout in the application module, atleast - it should, right now it uses the admin layout.twig by default.

How can I change this so it uses the application modules layout.twig (or a way to set the location of the layout file that's used?).

Sorry for the lack of code - hopefully it's a straightforward problem, the action just returns $viewData variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple

```
    $this->_helper->layout->setLayoutPath('YOU PATH TO LAYOUT IF PATH IS NOT INCLUDED THAN ADD FULL PATH');
    $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('YOUR LAYOUT FILE');
```

This code snippet shows how you set layout in controller. You add this two lines at top of your login action

Comment: I get an undefined property on $_helper, guessing this code is for an older version of ZF. The project is on ZF2, should have mentioned.

Comment: @RyanPilbeam than I am not an expert on zend framework 2 so I can't help anymore. I suggest you add zend framework 2 as tag and mention the project is in zend framework 2. thanks